# Chrome DevTools target discovery does not work anymore with node

Tags: google-chrome, node.js, google-chrome-devtools, debugger

I have a problem with chrome devTools who does not auto-discover target with any node process anymore.

For example, the following command `node --inspect=127.0.0.1:9400 index.js` return

```
Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9400/4478dde2-9b7e-483c-b4ec-65900a1c6922
For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector
Debugger attached.
server started at 5888
```

The chrome://inspect/ page show that [remote Target is detected](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yhY1f.png)
Bug when using the devTools from the "Open dedicated DevTools for Node" link the connection is not detected, the console and even the context selector are empty, see [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFOhK.png).

Everything worked before and i didn't changed anything...

Any idea where to look at ?

- Node Version 10.15.0
- Chrome Version 73.0.3683.75 (Official).

Answer (score 0):

I've experienced this too. Its a known issue at the moment, see here: https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/26887